# how to do I call a function in Swift

Tags: swift

can someone provide me with an example of how to use a function in swift? cause in objective-c id use `[self funcName]` but I can't seem to find one in swift. thanks for the help from anyone!

Comment: `self.funcName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uh, its pretty simple. just call the function

example:

```
functionName()
```

I recommend next time to look at the apple API on their developer site or do a bit more research before posting to stack overflow because some moderators will knock your question a lot. and if you get enough of those you risk losing the privilege of posting questions to the forum

here's the playground guide for you: https://books.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4-2/id881256329

Answer (score 1):

lol... pretty simple...

```
funcName
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just assume you are inside of a playground.

try running this example

```
func square(_ x:Int) -> Int {
    return x * x
}

print(square(3))
```

The first line declares a function who take one parameter of type Int and returns and Int. 
The function is called by simply typing the name of the function defined.

Please see https://books.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4-2/id881256329

in order to get a basic overview of the swift language. (assuming you have some experience in other languages) otherwise there might be better books out there if you are a total newbie.